# Google auth saying invalid code every time I try other method to log in without my security key on device without compatible port

Tags: security, authentication, usb-c, google-accounts

I set up a Google account with a USB-C security key, and I am trying to log in to a device that only has USB-A ports. I do not have a compatible adapter at the moment.

On the USB-A-only device when I go to log in it asks me to insert my security key, and I tap cancel, and then "Try another way". Google prompts me to go to `g.co/sc` and I opened that link on another device which can use the security key, authenticated, got a 6 digit code, and entered it in the field on the USB-A-only device asking for a code.

Unfortunately, it always says "This code is invalid" with every code I try.

Am I doing something wrong or is this just a very unfortunate bug with Google Auth?

Comment: a side note: Have you considered a USB-A male to USB-C female adapter - you can pick one up for under 5USD

Comment: Yes I got my hands on one and it worked, though I'm still curious why Google's workaround didn't work.